# Spelling: "number", "enum(b)erate", "num(b)erator", and so on

Tags: spelling

Why has the English language preserved the letter "b" in the word "number", but not in words like "enumerate" or "numerator" or "numerology" and so on?

Comment: Though it is not related to this question, I just personally thank you for asking some excellent questions in this site. Last couple of questions asked by you were really fantastic. Personally they helped me a lot. I appreciate your questions!

Comment: @Mistu, thank you. However I have asked better questions on Skeptics.SE, where I gained 11 nice-question badges in less than 100 days.

Answer (score 7):

*Number* entered English from French around the beginning of the 14th century, at which time the Latin *numerus* had already undergone sound changes which resulted in the Old French form *nombre*. The other words you mention were created later employing the original Latin root.